# Microsoft Graph - Saving file attachments through C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, attachment

Is it possible to save file attachments in C# through Microsoft Graph API?

I know I can get the properties of the attachment (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/attachment_get) - can we also save it to a certain location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the attachment properties, they will contain information about the attachment.

There are [three types](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/attachment_get#response) of attachments.

First, check the attachment type in the properties' `@odata.type` and handle them correspondingly.

For `fileAttachment` types, they contain a `contentLocation` attribute, which is [the URI of the attachment contents](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/fileattachment#properties).

You can download the attachment from the URI.

Comment: Hi, 
In my case, contentLocation is NULL. From what i understand, the answer from @Tomas is an alternative, where in we are saving contentbytes. How can one do the same in Javascript

Answer (score 11):

Once you have particular Microsoft Graph message, you can e.g. pass it to a method as parameter. Then you need to make another request to get attachments by message Id, iterate through attachments and cast it to `FileAttachment` to get access to the `ContentBytes` property and finally save this byte array to the file.

```
private static async Task SaveAttachments(Message message)
{
    var attachments = 
        await _client.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages[message.Id].Attachments.Request().GetAsync();

    foreach (var attachment in attachments.CurrentPage)
    {
        if (attachment.GetType() == typeof(FileAttachment))
        {
            var item = (FileAttachment)attachment; // Cast from Attachment
            var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(folder, item.Name);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, item.ContentBytes);
        }
    }
}
```