# Unable to read attachments from email using Outlook Graph API v2 in C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook-restapi, email-address

I am trying to read an email attachment using Microsoft Graph API(v2) but I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance" error

I have verified the app permissions in Azure Active Directory and has all the permissions set mentioned in microsoft documentation

Mail.Read
Group.Read.All (Added extra permission to try)
I am able to read the message and its content correctly and even the message "HasAttachments" property is true but when I call API again to fetch attachments it gives error.

Also tried to create new token for fetching attachments considering the fact that existing one would have expired but no luck

```
OutlookServicesClient client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri(OutlookAPI), GetAccessToken);

client.Context.SendingRequest2 +=
                    new EventHandler<Microsoft.OData.Client.SendingRequest2EventArgs>((sender, e) => InsertXAnchorMailboxHeader(sender, e, userEmail));
 var attachments = await client.Me.MailFolders.GetById(constInbox).Messages.GetById(strMessageID).Attachments.ExecuteAsync();


public async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
       string accessToken = null;
           using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(TokenUri);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                var requestContent = string.Format("grant_type=password" + "&client_id=" + appId +
                                                    "&client_secret=" + appPassword +
                                                    "&resource=" + Resource +
                                                    "&username=" + userEmail +
                                                   "&password=" + passwd);
                var content = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                var response = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content).Result;
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(result);
                accessToken = jobject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();
            }
            return accessToken;
        }
```

Attaching Quickwatch for client.Kindly check
[image: client on runtime]

Comment: The error says that some object is not set. Have you properly initialized `client1`? Please show a bit more of your code.

Comment: Following is the code I am using for initializing client:

 OutlookServicesClient client1 = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri(OutlookAPI), GetAccessToken);
                client.Context.SendingRequest2 +=
                    new EventHandler<Microsoft.OData.Client.SendingRequest2EventArgs>((sender, e) => InsertXAnchorMailboxHeader(sender, e, userEmail));

Comment: GetAccessToken() has following logic:
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                var requestContent = string.Format("grant_type=password" + "&client_id=" + appId +
                                                    "&client_secret=" + appPassword +
                                                    "&resource=" + Resource +
                                                    "&username=" + userEmail +
                                                   "&password=" + passwd);

Comment: Do I have to set any specific settings for reading attachments?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the additional code. It is rather difficult to read code in a comment and it lacks context if not shown in relation to the rest of the code. have you checked whether you get a proper Access Token? Have you set breakpoints and *verified* that client is correctly initialized?

Comment: Please check the edited post.I am getting access token correctly.Is there anything specific I have to check in client?

Comment: Ah yes. You initialize `client` **after** you call `await client.` <= There's the rub! Move the first line to the third.

Comment: Please check I am able to initialize client properly and also I am able to read mails appropriately.Let me know if you need any specific value

Comment: Not experienced in Graph API but according to documentation, your call `.Attachments.ExecuteAsync()` should rather be `.Attachments.Request().GetAsync();`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: Yes but it gives error when we write .Attachments.Request().GetAsync();....Error CS1061 'IAttachmentCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Request' and no accessible extension method 'Request'

Comment: You're still doing something wrong. It should work according to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-list-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp Please update your code to reflect your current status.

Comment: I was encountering the same behavior working with the `GraphServiceClient`. I needed to perform another request to get the attachments after the first query that got the message(s). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147472/microsoft-graph-saving-file-attachments-through-c) Specifically Tomáš Paul's answer helped me and may be what you need for the `OutlookServicesClient`